# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int' in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I m just following SVR tutorial in python

and I don't know how to solve this problem

I tried code as below and it keeps happening error

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'"

[image]
[image]

in the tutorial, it can get a result of y_pred.

Comment: specifically, post a minimal reproducible code, and not a screenshot - this will allow other users to better understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from unsupported usage of [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), which does not take `list` as input. Depending on what you actually want to achieve you can use `np.arange(6.5)`, which yields `array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])`. You will probably need to reshape this array, though: `np.arange(6.5).reshape(-1, 1)` will give you 7 one-dimensional samples.

On a general note, I would suggest against writing long, convoluted statements like in line 27, because they are hard to read, and even harder to debug.